# Proper List: Hidden () in Scheme Lists

Tags: scheme, racket

In Scheme, using `list` to define a list ensures that the result is a proper list, meaning that its final element is a list `()`.

If one defines a test list:

```
(define test (list 27 3))
```

And takes the `length` of the list, Racket says that it is 2. When one `prints` the list, it only displays `(27 3)`, not showing the `()`.

However, if one takes the `(rest (rest test))`, the `()` appears. Performing a `(list-ref test 2)` yields an error.

If the `()` appears as the 3rd element in the list when `cdr`ing through the elements, why isn't it considered a member of the list?

Wouldn't this create confusion between proper and improper lists in Scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is a chain of pairs. The elements are the `car`s of each pair, and each pair's `cdr` is a reference to the next pair in the chain.

The `cdr` of the last pair of a proper list is a reference to the special `()` object, which represents an empty list. It's not an element of the list because it's in the `cdr`, not the `car`.

The `rest` function returns the `cdr` of a pair. So `(rest (rest test))` is returning the second `cdr`, which is `()` because it's at the end of the list.

There's no confusion with improper lists. An improper list has something other than `()` as the `cdr` of the last pair in the chain.